# Customized Bootstrap Image Slider

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slider, carousel

I am new to Bootstrap 3 Carousel and was wondering if there's any way to display the current slider number when the image is changed, similar to the sample image below:
[image]

You can also notice that the navigation controls (left & right) are next to the current slide and the total number of slide.

I'm using [this tutorial](https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/bootstrap-3-carousel-tutorial/) as a reference and hoping you can help me out with other resources I can fork with. Thank you.

Comment: first of all here's an example of a slider with pics with titles and captions https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/hqcb6q13/ In this instance each slide div is called item. You would have to count the children of the div container to see how many child classes 'item' it contained. This would give you the total. The rest is just a matter of postioning really!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPD. I've added a javascript to calculate the number of slides in a carousel.

Please check the result: http://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/EKqZZN

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var selectIndicators = $('#myCarousel>.carousel-indicators>li');
  selectIndicators.each(function(i){
    $(this).text((i+1) + ' / ' + selectIndicators.length);
  }); 
});
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.container {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.carousel-inner {
  overflow: visible;
  width: 100%;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
  margin: auto;
  width: 70%;
}

.carousel-caption {
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: none;
  left: 70%;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.carousel-caption > h3 {
  color: #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-stretch: ultra-condensed;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 0 0 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
@media (min-width:  768px) { .carousel-caption > h3 { font-size: 24px; } }
@media (min-width:  992px) { .carousel-caption > h3 { font-size: 30px; } }
@media (min-width: 1200px) { .carousel-caption > h3 { font-size: 36px; } }
.carousel-caption > p {
  color: #000;
}
 
.carousel-control,
.carousel-control:hover {
  color: black;
  filter: none;
  opacity: 1;
  text-shadow: none;
  width: 30%;
}
.carousel-control.left,
.carousel-control.right {
  background-image: none;
}

.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right,
.carousel-indicators li,
.carousel-indicators li.active {
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right,
.carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left {
  left: 10px;
}
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
  right: 10px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
  .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
    right: auto;
    left: -395px; /* = 10px + 4 x 40px - 70% x Container width 750px */
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
    left: -549px; /* = 10px + 4 x 40px - 70% x Container width 970px */
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
    left: -689px; /* = 10px + 4 x 40px - 70% x Container width 1170px */
  }
}
.carousel-control:hover .glyphicon-chevron-left,
.carousel-control:hover .glyphicon-chevron-right {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
}

.carousel-indicators {
  left: 50px; /* = left + width form .glyphicon-chevron-left */
  width: auto;
}
.carousel-indicators li,
.carousel-indicators li.active {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: black;
  cursor: auto;
  display: none;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.carousel-indicators li.active {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x400/c69/?text=%20" alt="Slide 1">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Lorem<br>ipsum</h3>
          <p class="hidden-xs">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x400/69c/?text=%20" alt="Slide 2">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Lorem<br>ipsum</h3>
          <p class="hidden-xs">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x400/9c6/?text=%20" alt="Slide 3">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Lorem<br>ipsum</h3>
          <p class="hidden-xs">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div><!-- /.carousel -->
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: it looks good, but yes i think the whole point of the question was the js to auto calculate the number of slides. Adding it as a caption is a bit of a cop-out! Also I think he was after the customised arrows

Comment: @RachelGallen Thank you for your feedback. Javascript has been added. Please check the result.